# INSERT values into a table based on another table

Tags: mysql, insert

when we insert a product, we need to show it under various categories, categories are stored in table named tab_categories, below some sample data:

```
product     category
15          28
15          29
15          21
```

This means that the product 15 appears in categories  28,29,21

I am trying to write a query in MySQL and to select products based on the type (tid) of the product inside a table, named

```
tab_products
```

add product and category fields lines inside the table "tab_categories".

so I start by selecting products with:

```
SELECT * from tab_products WHERE tid = "1"
```

and after this I need to insert lines inside table tab_categories with the corresponding category field, like:

```
product     category
1       28
1       29
2       21
2       24
```

I have tried but I have no skills to write this query. can you help me please?

Comment: "I have tried…" Show what you've tried. Also, what are the columns on the `tab_products` table?

Comment: hello my friend, I have tried to read the documentation of insert... but my skills are very poor.. the tab_products table have many many fields, but i need to select products based on a field named "tid", other fields are not relevant for this specific question, really... so, can you help me?  thanks!

Comment: So where are you getting the category ID to insert into the `tab_categories` table? You should show a specific example including the data you're starting with in `tab_products`, and the desired result in `tab_categories`.

Comment: the category ID is something I will adjust based on the type ID of the product, each product will need to be put in different categories, so this will change always, i need to change it manually based on type ID, i just need to know how to select all products from table_products with type ID n. 1, for example, and then I will choose the category ids to be put inside the tab_categories, I hope you understand me.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine a `SELECT` statement with an `INSERT` statement:

```
SELECT col1, col2
INTO otherTable
FROM myTable
```

Comment: so it will look something like `SELECT ID, categoryID INTO tab_categories FROM tab_products WHERE typeID = 1` for example?

Comment: the point is that I need to specify multiple category IDs to be insert, for example, a product with type ID 1 need to be shown under category IDs 20, 21, 22.... So i need to UNDERSTAND how to accomplish this task.... select the products from table_products based on type id (tid) and then insert into tab_categories for each selected product one line for each category where the product need to be shown, got me?

Comment: Yea your example works. With regards to multiple conditions, you might want to check out `OR`'s and `AND`s. If you want to match multiple ID numbers, `IN()` is also good to look up.

Comment: i need to understand how to insert specific numbers inside tab_category in categoy field, I dont understand how to do this, pleas help